# How get Url file from Firebase after Upload to return Url String sent to Backend and save DataBase My SQL

Tags: angular, firebase, spring-boot

I am new member for Angular.

I am doing project have using techologies:

- Back-end: Spring Boot
- Front- End: Angular
- Database:

*My SQL to save infor type String ( text, ....)

- FireBase to save infor type file ( mp3, pdf, png...vv)

I done push and get file from FireBase to Angular.

But, I don't want get file directly from Firebase.

Target: I want get url file from Fire Base to sent request to Backend and save url file at My SQL.

Then, when binding data ( include text and file) will use backend and My SQL

So, Can you help me to get Url file from Fire Base ?

Thank you so much.

First, I make object Upload file.
Second, I make service upload file.( Pushfile, getfile)
Third, I write component.ts ( DI service in contructur)
 - I make variable is fileupload: any[] = []
 - I call to service using getfile method.
 - Save List file to fileupload.
 - Then, I want get url from fileupload but not perfect. 
Fourth, I write component.html

Comment: Which method you are using for file upload in firebase?

Comment: @PareshGami
I cann't comment at here. I commented to you by bottom post.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

@Paresh Gami
Service of My project make 6 methods with FireBase:

1. Push file
2. Save file
3. Get file
4. Delete file
5. Delete file Database
6. Delete file Storage

This is Code of **Push file**

```
pushFileToStorage(fileUpload: FileUpload, progress: { percentage: number }) {
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
const uploadTask = storageRef
  .child(`${this.basePathFile}/${fileUpload.file.name}`)
  .put(fileUpload.file);

uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
  (snapshot) => {
                              const snap = snapshot as firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot;
                              progress.percentage = Math.round((snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100);},
          (error) => { console.log(error); },
  () => {
              uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
                console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
                fileUpload.url = downloadURL;
                fileUpload.name = fileUpload.file.name;
                this.saveFileData(fileUpload); });
  }
);
```

}

This is **Get File**

```
 getFileUploads(numberItems): AngularFireList<FileUpload> {
    return this.db.list(this.basePathFile, ref => ref.limitToLast(numberItems));
```

}